# build with angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Having issues to build my angular app with angularcli.On ng build command it shows following error. What am i missing.

```
 You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command.
```

A Sample one works well. However the old project has this issue. The old project were not created by 'ng new' the angular-cli.json and entries in package.json were added manually. Which did build for a while and with all the compatible version changes with cli, angular, rxjs and zone now it is stuck with this error

ng --version gives me the following

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.11.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.3.1
@angular/compiler: 2.3.1
@angular/core: 2.3.1
@angular/forms: 2.3.1
@angular/http: 2.3.1
@angular/platform-browser: 2.3.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.3.1
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/upgrade: 2.0.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.3.1
```

package.json has following entries and more

```
"name": "project1",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Application to capture info",
"angular-cli": {},
...
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
...
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
```

and a standard angular-cli.json

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": ".",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "app/main.ts",
```

Comment: Show your current directory in your cli

Comment: how do i add an image here

Comment: Directory of D:\workspace\code\project.Web
    16/08/2017  12:35 PM         1,271 angular-cli.json
    07/07/2017  04:42 PM       144,712 package-lock.json
    16/08/2017  04:15 PM         2,368 package.json
    16/08/2017  05:53 PM           331 tsconfig.json
    22/02/2017  09:44 PM         1,896 tslint.json
    22/02/2017  09:44 PM           367 typings.json
           6 File(s)    150,945 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  1,010,323,546,112 bytes free
    D:\workspace\code\project.Web>ng build --prod

    You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be inside your project directory. In terminal window, do

```
cd YourProjectName
ng build
```

You can still see angular-cli version, because you installed it globally on your computer

Comment: Sure am trying ng build in the folder. I tried ng new project..   cd project.. Which was building, note it has the same issue

Comment: I mean "now it has same issue"

Comment: Have you deleted any files or have you done npm install?

Comment: Maybe your your local installation is failing, so please reinstall angular cli, following this steps : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Comment: Yes I have been doing npm cache clean,  npm install... did npm uninstall of angularcli globally and installed again globally. have lost count.

Comment: Sample one works well. However the old project has same issue. The old project were not create by 'ng new' the angular-cli.json and entries in package.json were added manually. Which did build for a while and with all the compatible version changes with cli, angular, rxjs and zone now it is stuck with this error

Comment: True that is how I ended up with sample application. Once I had all the node_modules removed and npm install, got better errors. In between I had lost angular-cli entry in package.json which gave same error.